# Adding an IBAction button to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a simple view controller with a few buttons that are defined as IBActions. I want to place them on a scroll view, basically making the whole page scrollable (let's say they are really big buttons and I have a bunch of them). How can I do that? I tried to add those buttons, but since they are defined as IBAction it did not work.

Here is some of my code. thanks!

```
- (IBAction) switchFromThird : (id)sender
{
    //some action...
}

- (IBAction) BackHome : (id)sender
{
     //some action...   
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];    

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 1000);
myScroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
myScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
myScroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
myScroll.delegate = self;


[myScroll addSubview:switchFromThird]; //???
[myScroll addSubview:BackHome]; //???


[myScroll release];
}
```

Comment: "a few buttons that are defined as IBActions" ... what?

Comment: the two IBActions above are connected to UIButtons on the IB. So every time you click on them, this method is being invoked. They are not declared as UIButton in the code though.

Comment: They are not defined, because they can't be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, no, no.

Please read [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594) in iOS Developer Library. You can't add a **method (function)** to a **view**! It's like you wanted to have a computer program in your printed document on a sheet of paper!

You should do something like this:

1. Write `IBOutlet UIButton *BackHomeButton` in your **.h** file.
2. Open your **.xib** file.
3. Connect the `BackHomeButton` outlet to your button
4. Replace `[myScroll addSubview:BackHome];` with `[myScroll addSubview:BackHomeButton];`.

**Then, and only then** it will work. As I said: you can print only images and text, not computer programs!

Comment: This is nice, but what about the action? I Want something to happen when someone clicks on it? How do I associate the action with this button?

Comment: In your IB, open your "Outlets" tab and connect "Touch Up Inside" with "File's Owner"

Comment: Ohh I see...so I needed to connect the UI button on IB TWICE...weird it worked with just connecting it to an action. Now lets see if it adds to the scroll view...thanks!!!

Comment: @Kashiv, if he's already created the button in Interface Builder, he doesn't need to call `addSubview:` with the buttons at all.  Consequently, he doesn't need to hook up the `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @TommyG, if you add an `IBOutlet` in this way, remember that it then becomes your responsibility to release the memory for the buttons, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

`IBAction`s are not buttons.  They are methods that are specially marked so that Interface Builder can find them easily.  You still need to create your buttons.

You can do this in Interface Builder by dragging them from the object library onto your scrollview.  You can then hook them up to your `IBAction` by right-mouse-button-dragging from your new button to whichever object you are defining the `IBAction` on.

If you prefer to create your buttons programmatically, you'll need to call `[[UIButton alloc[ init`... and then connect the button to your method with the button's `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method.  It's not necessary to declare your methods as `IBAction`s in this case, that's just something Apple put in to make it easier for Interface Builder to find relevant methods.

Comment: Thats what I did - I dragged those UIButtons from the library on IB and linked them (with the right click, etc.) to the respective IBAction. I did not, however, declared any UIButton in my code. So right now, I have a view with a few buttons, each linked to an IBAction on IB, but no UIButton declarations whatsoever. This all work perfectly, I just dont know how to add them to my scroll view now.

Comment: If you created them in Interface Builder, you can just drag them directly onto the scroll view.  You don't have to do it programmatically.